# Update Table headers from a dymanic array in JavaScript/ Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

This is my update function for updating table headers from a dynamic array which I am collecting from checkbox selected, now when I click a button to call this function, I want to update my table headers but what is happening new updated array elements got appended with previous headers, on button click I want to update the table headers as per new array?. Please ask for clarification if required. Skip top 3 lines and use arr1 as an array to create table headers.

```
    <script>
    function updateTable() {
    /*var arr1 = [];  //this is the array
    $.each($("input[name='cols']:checked"), function (){
        arr1.push($(this).val());
    });*/
    var arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
    // First create thead section
    $('#dispTab').append('<thead><tr></tr></thead>');
    // Then create your head elements
    $thead = $('#dispTab > thead > tr:first');
    for (var i = 0, len = arr1.length; i < len; i++) {
        $thead.append('<th>'+arr1[i]+'</th>');
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: _“Please ask for clarification if required”_ - please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Question is not clear... What do you want as output? All the array elements should be displayed in the thead???

Comment: @Mittal Yes thats what is required??

Answer (score 0):

try `html()` instead of `append()` as below

```
 $thead.find("th").eq(i).html(arr1[i]);
```